# Is DynamoDB Adaptive Capacity only for provisioned table?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have read the Amazon DynamoDB documentation and I was wondering:

- is DynamoDB Adaptive Capacity only for provisioned table ? (and not for on-demand mode) ?

if I create a DynamoDB table with on-demand mode, DynamoDB will scale the partitions by splitting an existing partition (if the 10GB max capacity AND/OR the 3000RCU and 1000WCU hard limit of any partition is reached).

In that situation, I don't understand how adaptive capacity would work (it is not possible to exceed the hard limit of a partition, DynamoDB HAS to split the partition).

The split behavior based on the RCUs / WCUs hard limit of a partition seems the be called "split for heat" ?

From this blog post:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/part-3-scaling-dynamodb-how-partitions-hot-keys-and-split-for-heat-impact-performance/

> Adaptive capacity capabilities including split for heat and burst
> capacity work on both base tables and GSIs.

So the DynamoDB splitting behavior based on the hard limit of a partition (="split for heat") seems to be a subset of the Adaptive Capacity feature ?
I am a bit confused, to me, these are 2 different concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, Adaptive Capacity comes with multiple features.

1. Direct capacity to unbalanced consumption (The core feature for provisioned mode, which eliminates partition dilution)
2. Split for Heat -> Partitions which are deemed "hot", when capacity exceeds a defined threshold for a sustained period of time, are split into multiple partitions.
3. Split for Size -> Partitions which begin to scale towards 10GB of storage are split into multiple partitions.

Comment: Thank you! So for a table using on-demand mode, there is no concept of adaptive capacity ?

Comment: There is for #2 and #3 but not feature #1 as it doesn't have the partition dilution issue like provisioned mode had (before adaptive capacity)

Comment: Makes sense, thank you. I didn't understand that Adaptive capacity means all these things (for me it was just the increase of the soft limit of a partition to handle hot partitions)